# SUM of users in each team and their status

Tags: mysql, sql

The code is a query that should return the number of users in each team and their status.
The code starts by joining all the teams for a user to get the total number of users in each team.
Then it joins those queues with the agent to get how many agents are ready, busy, offline, or unknown.
The result is then grouped by status and ordered by status.

```
USE database
SELECT Team.team_name as 'Team name',
      SUM(CASE WHEN User.status = 'Available' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Users available',
      SUM(CASE WHEN User.status = 'Away' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Users away',
      SUM(CASE WHEN User.status = 'Offline' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Users offline'
FROM User
JOIN USER_TEAM ON User.user_id = USER_TEAM.User
JOIN Team ON USER_TEAM.Team = Team.team_id
GROUP BY User.status, Team.team_name
ORDER BY User.status, Team.team_name
```

Here's the preview of the Users table:
[image: Users table]

Here's the preview of the Teams table:
[image: Teams table]

Here's the preview of the User_Team table:
[image: User_Team table]

The users are assigned to different teams. Some of them might be assigned to multiple teams at once.

The result that I get from that code is:
[image: Result table]

The desired result that I want to achieve would be:
[image: Desired result table]

I'm not really sure how to proceed with "merging" multiple rows that are returned into one that sums up all the available/away/offline per team.

I've tried to experiment with different types of JOINs to find the matching records but eventually, I did not manage to find a working solution.
How do I proceed to achieve the desired table?

Comment: Remove `User.status` from `GROUP BY` & `ORDER BY` you might get your expectation, because it didn't need to display from your expect result

Comment: in your given data team C is assigned those users where status in away and offline. But your desired result it assigns also in available status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOIN three tables and GROUP with teams name and use condition inside aggregate function. No need to use status in group by and order by portion as this is used in aggregate function.

```
SELECT t.team_name as 'Team name'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN u.status = 'Available' then 1 end) as 'Users available'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN u.status = 'Away' then 1 end) as 'Users away'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN u.status = 'Offline' then 1 end) as 'Users offline'
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN User_Team ut 
        ON u.user_id = ut.user_id
INNER JOIN Teams t 
        ON ut.team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY t.team_name
ORDER BY t.team_name;
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b5708911972e9325b67b16ee7780d2f7